# Are drugs made bitter artificially to prevent being mistaken for candy?

Tags: pharmacology, sensation, perception, taste, medicinal-chemistry

All drugs I remember tasting (with the notable exception of Aspirin) have bitter taste. Is the taste due to the active substance, or is a bittering agent added to them, perhaps to prevent overdose?

Take Paracetamol for instance: adult pills taste bitter, while the syrup for babies is sweet without any noticeable bitterness. Or is the dosage simply so low that I couldn't distinguish the drug taste behind all that sugar they put in?

Comment: Why do you think aspirin doesn't taste bitter?

Comment: Not sure why Dmitry said it, but I know that some Ibuprofen (who many call "aspirin") are covered in a sort of 'candy shell' which is bit sweet to my senses as well. I've never had Acetaminophen that were coated, but I use the Ibuprofen that is coated specifically because I don't have to rush the chaser to get the taste out so fast.

Comment: Or perhaps he's only used that expensive coated brand, instead of the generic stuff.  So he's never actually tasted the aspirin.

Comment: I've seen paracetamol confused with aspirin, not ibuprofen with aspirin. Ibuprofen itself shouldn't be tasted, since it's usually either shelled or in a liquid-cap for good reason @coblr

Comment: @jamesqf Because I tasted it. Aspirin is an acid and has a typical sour taste.

Comment: @coblr, Not sure which part of my question you a referring to. The sweet paracetamol I was talking about was for babies, so it was certainly not in "candy shell", as babies cannot swallow pills without the risk of choking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a problem in biology, but is solely about commercial/social marketing practice. It may possibly be relevant on SE Medical Sciences.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev: Apparently your taste buds are more sophisticated, or perhaps I should say capable of greater discrimination, than mine are, because I certainly can't tell the difference.

Comment: @coblr you may be confusing Aspirin with Advil, which is a brand name for ibuprofen. Aspirin is acetylsalicylic acid

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't so much confusing it as I was just pointing out that many that don't know/could care less about the specific compound (including my wife) will call Advil an "Aspirin" in a similar way to how people call facial tissues a "Kleenexes", sodas "cokes" and vacuums, "Hoovers". I didn't realize that baby Aspirin had something extra or that, that's what was being referred to. It was just a reason I could think of for why a certain type of "Aspirin" may have been sweeter than expected. I didn't assume an adult was taking baby aspirin when it wasn't mentioned as such.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Short answer**
A bittering agent may be applied to therapeuticals to prevent pediatric poisonings, but many drugs inherently taste bitter by themselves.

**Background**
Bitter taste is thought to have evolved as a way to decrease the risk of ingesting toxic substances, which may explain why many drugs taste bitter. In other words, classes of compounds that may harm the body often taste bitter [(Menella *et al*., 2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3772669/). These include the often dangerous compounds like [**alkaloids**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaloid#:%7E:text=Alkaloids%20are%20a%20class%20of,may%20also%20be%20termed%20alkaloids.) and [**glycosides**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycoside#:%7E:text=In%20chemistry%2C%20a%20glycoside%20%2F%CB%88,the%20form%20of%20inactive%20glycosides.) (source: [University of Delhi](http://bcas.du.ac.in/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Basic-chemicals.pdf)). These include the familiar psychotropic compounds found in hallucinogenic plants, and the potentially deadly heart glycosides found in *Digitalis* species, respectively, among other classes of substances.

Paracetamol can be regarded as an alkaloid (Fig. 1), but not aspirin, as it lacks a nitrogen atom (Fig. 2). An **[alkaloid](https://www.britannica.com/science/alkaloid)** is defined as

> any of a class of naturally occurring organic **nitrogen-containing bases**. Alkaloids have diverse and important physiological effects on humans and other animals. Well-known alkaloids include morphine, strychnine, quinine, ephedrine, and nicotine...

All of which are quite toxic. As cleverly noted in the comments, aspirin is not an alkaloid in its strictest sense, as it is not naturally occurring. However, it is chemically obtained by [acetylation of salicylic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Acetylation_of_salicylic_acid,_mechanism.png) [(Mund *et al*., 2016)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4944482/), as shown in Fig. 2. Both of the reactants in themselves are naturally occurring; [salicylic acid can  be sourced from willow bark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_aspirin), and acetylation is a widely occurring biochemical reaction [(Gibbs, 2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4601045/).

I myself have never had the chance to taste aspirin, unfortunately (although I performed the acetylation shown in Fig. 2 for my Organic Chemistry class :-). Originally, aspirin was developed from salicylic acid (Fig. 3) just because the taste of salicylic acid was so bitter. Acetylation diminished the bitterness, yet the anti-inflammatory action remained [(Wu, 2000)](https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/01.CIR.102.17.2022)). Besides reducing bitterness by chemical modification, masking the bitterness of drugs with, *e.g.*., sweeteners, can help to overcome the aversion to the bitter taste. This can aid in helping patients, especially pediatric ones, to take their medicine and adhere to their treatment regime [(Chauhan, 2017)](https://www.imedpub.com/articles/taste-masking-a-unique-approach-for-bitter-drugs.php?aid=20177).

Reversely, coming back to your question, adding bitter-tasting additives to drugs indeed seem to be an effective way to reduce pediatric poisonings [(Menella *et al*., 2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3772669/)

<sub>**References**

**-** [Chauhan, *J stem cell Bio transplant* (2014); **1**(2): 12](https://www.imedpub.com/articles/taste-masking-a-unique-approach-for-bitter-drugs.php?aid=20177)

**-** [Gibbs, *Trends Plant Sci* (2015); **20**(10): 599–601](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4601045/)

**-** [Menella *et al*., Clin Ther. 2013 Aug; 35(8): 1225–1246](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3772669/)

**-** [Mund *et al.*, *J Occup Med Toxicol* (2016); **11**: 32](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4944482/)

**-** [Wu, *Circulation* (2000); **102**: 2022–3](https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/01.CIR.102.17.2022)</sub>

[image: paracetamol]
<sub>Fig. 1. Paracetamol, or acetaminophen. source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Paracetamol-skeletal.svg)</sub>

[image: Synthesis of Aspirin]
<sub>Fig. 2. Synthesis of Aspirin, or acetylsalycilic acid, from salicylic acid. source: [Imperial College, UK](https://www.ch.ic.ac.uk/rzepa/mim/drugs/html/aspirin.htm)</sub>

Comment: I recall an advert in the 90s advertising a form of aspirin "without the aspirin taste" - it showed a bunch of people taking aspirin dissolved in water, screwing up their faces.  I also recall experiencing the same.  I can't find the advert anywhere however, and I haven't taken aspirin in years.

Comment: Interesting read: [The importance of taste in pharmaceutical development](https://manufacturingchemist.com/news/article_page/The_importance_of_taste_in_pharmaceutical_development/134604) but that yummy chewable baby aspirin now seems somehow evil...

Comment: @RossPresser Notably, nowadays aspirin is the last thing you want to give to a kid because it might cause [brain damage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reye_syndrome).